# Use split in as delimiter

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have many .txt file in one location. This txt content is as below.

`%-ile |  Read (ms) | Write (ms) | Total (ms)`

`----------------------------------------------`

`min |        N/A |      0.018 |      0.018`

`25th |        N/A |      0.055 |      0.055`

`50th |        N/A |      0.059 |      0.059`

`75th |        N/A |      0.062 |      0.062`

`90th |        N/A |      0.070 |      0.070`

`95th |        N/A |      0.073 |      0.073`

`99th |        N/A |      0.094 |      0.094`

`3-nines |        N/A |      0.959 |      0.959`

`4-nines |        N/A |     67.552 |     67.552`

`5-nines |        N/A |     75.349 |     75.349`

`6-nines |        N/A |     84.994 |     84.994`

`7-nines |        N/A |     85.632 |     85.632`

I am reading **3-nines** from above content and want to write a program like it **Total (ms)** column's value in greater than 1 with respect to 3-nines row it should print that file name.
For that I have written a program as below:

```
$data = get-content "*.txt" | Select-String -Pattern "3-nines"
$data | foreach {
$items = $_.split("|")
if ($items[0] -ge 1 ) {Echo $items[1]}
}
```

But getting below error.

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'split'.
At line:2 char:18
+ $items = $_.split <<<< ("|")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (split:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Cannot index into a null array.
At line:3 char:12
+ if ($items[ <<<< 0] -lt 1 ) {Echo $items[1]}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Could you please help here. I am very new to the powershell scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$items = $_.split("|")
```

to:

```
$items = ([string]$_).split("|")
```

The contents of the match is returned as an array and it doesn't have a split method. Casting it to a string will give you the split method.

**Update:** To print the filename you have to change the script a bit since the current input for Select-String is an array so you loose the filename:

```
Select-String -Pattern "3-nines" -Path "*.txt" | foreach {
    $items = ([string]$_).split("|")
    if ([double]$items[3] -ge 1 ) { 
        Write-Output "FileName: $($_.Filename)" 
        Echo $items[3]
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Francois . Could you please know one more thing that how can I print that .txt file name where $items[3] values is greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - why would you pipe to `Select-String` here? You can use `-Path` parameter and pass `*.txt` directly to it.

The reason split doesn't work is because you should call it agains `Line` property of `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]` object. I guess what you need there is a simple `Where-Object`:

```
Select-String -Pattern 3-nines -Path *.txt | 
    Where-Object { [double]($_.line.Split('|')[-1]) -gt 1 } | 
    Select-Object Path, Line
```

Alternatively, you can turn content of the file into objects with `Import-Csv` cmdlet:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path *.txt) {
    # Existing headers are terrible - replacing them...
    $3nines = Import-Csv -Path $file.FullName -Delimiter '|' -Header Percent, Read, Write, Total |
        Where-Object Percent -match 3-nines 
    if ([double]$3nines.Total -gt 1) {
        $3nines | Select-Object *, @{
            Name = 'Path'
            Expression = { $file.FullName }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not able to vote for two answers otherwise this also works for me. Thanks again.